# Segmentation fault of reading elements from an array C++

Tags: c++, cuda

I have these code lines following:

```
load()
{
    float* host;
    // init host done

    float** tran;

    printf("testing...\n");

    transpose(host, tran, 600);

    printf("testing. 3..\n");

    printf(" value =%d \n", tran[0][0]); // segmentation here

    printf("done...\n");
}

void transpose(float *input, float** output, int width)
{
    int size = 128*width*sizeof(float);

    // Allocate space on the GPU for input and output
    float* GPU_input = 0;   
    float** GPU_output;

    cudaMalloc(&GPU_input, size);
    cudaMalloc(&GPU_output, size);

    // Copy the input data to the GPU (host to device)
    cudaMemcpy(GPU_input, input, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 threads(32, 32);
    dim3 grid(width/32+1, 128/32);

    printf("OK...\n");

    kernel_transpose<<< grid, threads >>>(GPU_input, GPU_output);

    printf("OK 2...\n");

    // Copy the input data to the GPU (host to device)
    cudaMemcpy(output, GPU_output, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("OK 3...\n");

    cudaFree(GPU_input);
    cudaFree(GPU_output);

    printf("testing. 2..\n");
}

__global__ void kernel_transpose(float *array, float** output)
{
    int index_x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int index_y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    output[index_x][index_y] = array[index_x+index_y];
}
```

compiling and running I got:

> ```
> testing...
> OK...
> OK 2...
> OK 3...
> testing. 2..
> testing. 3..
> line 84: 26819 Segmentation fault
> ```

Why I got "segmentation fault"?and if possible, how to fix it?

Comment: What is line 84 and where do `testing. 2` and `testing. 3` get printed?

Comment: @Bart, I updated it for "testing 2 and 3". Segmentation here// at line 84

Comment: where do you allocate input and output?

Comment: @neagoegab input and output are called from transpose() inside load(). input is allocated correctly

Comment: @neagoegab yes, it is ok to do it like that

Comment: sorry but they are not allocated at all... and also passing pointer to pointer to pointer in case of GPU_output is a problem...

Comment: `tran[0]` is a pointer of type: `(float *)` in this case, not a 'row' offset.

Comment: @BrettHale can you explain in more detail, I think I'm tired at this hour...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`host` and `tran` need to be allocated and initialized before you use them. For example, in C you'd use `malloc` and `free`, making sure you test the return values in case of allocation errors:

```
// for strerror
#include <string.h>
...

int iobufsize(width) {
    return 128*width*sizeof(float);
}

float** alloc_matrix(...) {
    float **matrix, *pool;
    int i, eno=0;
    // allocate array of array pointers
    if ((matrix = (float**)malloc( ... ))) {
        /* Allocate array to hold data. This array will be divided up to
           create the arrays used in the matrix. Alternatively, each matrix array
           could be allocated separately.
         */
        if ((pool = (float*) malloc( ... ))) {
            for (i=0; i < ... ; i++) {
                // each item in matrix points to a subarray of the data array
                matrix[i] = pool + i * ...;
            }
        } else {
            /* free() shouldn't change errno, but this isn't guaranteed 
               for every implementation, so save errno to be safe.
             */
            eno = errno;
            free(matrix);
            errno = eno;
            matrix = NULL;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
void free_matrix(float **matrix, ...) {
    if (matrix) {
        free(*matrix);
        free(matrix);
    }
}

void load() {
    float* host;
    float** tran;
    int width = 600;
    int size = iobufsize(width);

    if ((host = (float*)malloc(size))) {
        if ((tran = alloc_matrix( ... ))) {
            // initialize 'host' buffer somehow
            ...

            printf("testing\n");

            transpose(host, tran, width);

            printf("testing 3\n");
            printf(" value =%d \n", tran[0][0]);
            printf("done\n");

            free_matrix(tran, ...);
            free(host);
        } else {
            /* Note: strerror isn't thread safe. If load() is run concurrently,
               make use of strerror_r instead.
             */
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate output buffer: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            free(host);
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate input buffer: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

As an improvement, you can bundle the matrix (array of array pointers) into a struct along with the matrix dimensions. This is a step towards creating a matrix class.

In C++, you'd use `new[]` and `delete[]`, make classes for `host` and `tran`, which would be members of another class that manages the interaction . This simplifies memory management (especially whenever `new[]` throws a [`bad_alloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/bad_alloc/)) because you can apply the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern.

There's quite a few other issues with your code. When you allocate (such as with `cudaMalloc`) or copy (such as with `cudaMemcpy`) memory, no semantics (such as pointer semantics) are applied to the contents. This has a number of implications in your code. For one thing, each allocation can only give you a 1 dimensional array. If you want higher dimensional arrays, you must allocate arrays of pointers to lower-dimensional arrays, allocate the lower dimensional arrays and then set the pointers in the higher dimensional array to point to the lower dimensional arrays (as outlined in `alloc_matrix`). `cudaMalloc(&GPU_output, size);`, for example, creates a 1-dimensional array of `float**`, but doesn't initialize the contents. As a result, you don't have a valid array of array pointers.

Additionally, the size of `GPU_output` is wrong; `size` is the overall data size, not the size for the higher dimensional array. This mistake arises from treating 1 and 2 dimensional arrays the same; they're not. A 1-dimensional array is a contiguous memory region, where the contents are a sequence of objects that all have the same layout (i.e. the array items are homogeneous). A 2-dimensonal array is an array of pointers to arrays. In both cases, the code accesses the arrays via pointers to the first item of the array (e.g. `host` is a pointer to the first float datum, `trans` is a pointer to the first pointer to the first array, which is a pointer to the first float datum). `alloc_matrix` structures the arrays so that you can easily treat the data as having 1 or 2 dimensions because the arrays are themselves contiguous (they're taken from the contiguous memory region pointed to by `pool`). `host[x][y]` treats the data as having 2 dimensions. `(*host)[x*n+y]` (or `host[0][x*n+y]`), where `n` is the size of a single data array, treats the data as having 1 dimension.

What you've got:

```
float **GPU_output --> | float* | -> random memory location
                       | float* | -> random memory location
                          ....       (size / sizeof(float**) pointers total)
                       | float* | -> random memory location
```

What you want

```
float **GPU_output --> | float* | --> | float |
                                      | float |
                                         ...     
                                      | float |
                       | float* | --> | float |
                                      | float |
                                         ...     
                                      | float |  
                                  ...            
                       | float* | --> | float |
                                      | float |
                                         ...     
                                      | float |
```

Comment: yes, host is allocated before with init... tran is copied from  cudaMemcpy(output, GPU_output, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

Comment: @devn: the sample code doesn't show either `host` or `tran` as being allocated. You need to allocate `tran`, otherwise you're copying to a random location. The [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is incomplete and non-representative if the production code allocates `host` and `tran` and this isn't shown in the sample. Sample code should precisely reproduce the issue with the production code, not introduce its own errors.

Comment: @devn but where is copied tran? where in memory?

Comment: @neagoegab is it not right that the transpose() add "tran" as a parameter and you can see that "tran" is allocated from here: cudaMemcpy(output, GPU_output, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); the output is tran. Is this correct?

Comment: @devn Yes `cudaMemcpy` copies data from device to host, but if there is no memory allocated for `tran` it doesn't magically allocate memory for it.

Comment: @ChristianRau anyway how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @devn: allocate memory for them using a C standard library routine like `malloc` or the C++ `new` operator. But the underlying solution is to go and study some learning material on the concept of pointers in C, because clearly you don't understand them, and trying to program a distributed memory architecture like CUDA will be an exercise in futility until you do....